# verilog AND gate when 32 not working correctly

Tags: verilog, iverilog

The AND gate

```
module andgate
#(parameter Port_Num = 2, 
 parameter WIDTH=8) 
 (
 input [(WIDTH-1):0] a,
 input [(WIDTH-1):0] b,
 input [(WIDTH-1):0] c,
 input [(WIDTH-1):0] d,
 input [(WIDTH-1):0] e,
 input [(WIDTH-1):0] f,
 input [(WIDTH-1):0] g,
 input [(WIDTH-1):0] h,
 output [(WIDTH-1):0] q
 );
 assign q = (a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h);
endmodule
```

The angate_sim

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module andgate_sim();
    // input 
    reg a=0;
    reg b=0;
    reg c=1;
    reg d=1;
    reg e=1;
    reg f=1;
    reg g=1;
    reg h=1;
    //outbut
    wire q;
    andgate #(8,1) u(.a(a),.b(b),.c(c),.d(d),.e(e),.f(f),.g(g),.h(h),.q(q)); 

    always #100 a=~a;
    initial begin
        #100 a=1;
        #100 begin a=0;b=1;end
        #100 a=1;
        #60000000 $finish;
    end

    initial
    begin            
        $dumpfile("wave2.vcd");        
        $dumpvars(0, andgate_sim);    
    end

endmodule
```

When I test the testbench, it worked correctly like this

```
iverilog -o Ex2 andgate.v andgate_sim.v
vvp -n Ex2 -lxt2
gtkwave wave2.vcd
```

[The successful wave in wave2.vcd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbysV.png)

Then I tried to make a AND gate*32 just like this

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module andgate32_sim( );
// input 
 reg [31:0] a=32'h00000000;
 reg [31:0] b=32'h00000000;
 reg [31:0] c=32'hffffffff;
 reg [31:0] d=32'hffffffff;
 reg [31:0] e=32'hffffffff;
 reg [31:0] f=32'hffffffff;
 reg [31:0] g=32'hffffffff;
 reg [31:0] h=32'hffffffff;
 //outbut
 wire [31:0] q;

andgate #(8,32) u(.a(a),.b(b),.c(c),.d(d),.e(e),.f(f),.g(g),.h(h),.q(q)); 


always  #100 
    begin
    a <= 32'hffffffff;
    end
always  #200 
    begin
      a <= 32'h00000000;
      b <= 32'hffffffff;
    end
always  #300 
    begin
    a <= 32'h007fa509;
    end
always  #400 
    begin
    a <= 32'hffffffff;
    end 


initial  begin
 #100 a <= 32'hffffffff;
 #100 begin a <= 32'h00000000;b <= 32'hffffffff;end
 #100 a <= 32'h007fa509;
 #100 a <= 32'hffffffff;
 #60000000 $finish;
 end

initial
begin            
    $dumpfile("wave2-2.vcd");        
    $dumpvars(0, andgate32_sim);  
end

endmodule
```

But when I did the steps like before

```
iverilog -o Ex2 andgate.v andgate32_sim.v
vvp -n Ex22 -lxt2
gtkwave wave2-2.vcd
```

There was nothing in the wave like this

[No waves in the wave2-2.vcd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFwke.png)
Actaully, it should be something in the wave2-2.vcd.
**Could you please help me ?**

Comment: btw, not probably related to the issue, but it is better not to use non-blocking assignment anywhere  in your code.

Comment: @Serge <= is for clocked sequential logic;  = is for combinational. Consult literally any introductory verilog text for learn the difference.

Comment: @TomServo thank you for your input, but there is no sequential clocked logic in the example above. NBAs there can end up in creating races in other parts of the code.

Comment: @Serge Agreed, you're right of course. Just with newbies, your earlier advice could be misinterpreted in a most harmful way.  Someone might interpret it as "never use NBA anywhere in any code" like "never use `scanf()` in C"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run another compiled testbench "Ex22" instead of "Ex2".

Hint: You can use parameters and pass them to the instantiation, as:

```
localparam WIDTH = 32;
localparam Port_Num = 8;

// input
 reg [WIDTH-1:0] a=32'h00000000;
 reg [WIDTH-1:0] b=32'h00000000;
 reg [WIDTH-1:0] c=32'hffffffff;
 reg [WIDTH-1:0] d=32'hffffffff;
 reg [WIDTH-1:0] e=32'hffffffff;
 reg [WIDTH-1:0] f=32'hffffffff;
 reg [WIDTH-1:0] g=32'hffffffff;
 reg [WIDTH-1:0] h=32'hffffffff;
 //outbut
 wire [WIDTH-1:0] q;

andgate #(.Port_Num (Port_Num), .WIDTH (WIDTH)) u(.a(a),.b(b),.c(c),.d(d),.e(e),.f(f),.g(g),.h(h),.q(q));
```

Comment: You guys are so nice, emm I do the testbench with vivado, but I do no know what is in that  testbench file created by vivado.